# Múltiplas chaves estrangeiras numa única consulta

Tags: php, mysql, query

Bom, estou tendo alguns problemas para a criação de uma consulta em mysql que busque diversos dados de diversas tabelas numa única query, eu procurei aqui no stack, encontrei algumas perguntas semelhantes, porém não consegui compreender a lógica ou método utilizado, e o "por que?" de ser daquele jeito.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

cartas:

`ID|nome_carta|id_edicao|id_tipo|efeito_desc|atk|def|link_img|id_atributo|id_lrl|quantidade`

atributos:

`ID|atributo`

edicoes:

`ID|nome_edicao|serial`

tipos:

`ID|tipo`

Como posso realizar a consulta para ter o seguinte resultado ?

`Nome_Carta|Nome_Edição|Serial|Tipo|Efeito|ATK|DEF|IMG|Atributo|LRL|Quantidade`

Comment: Tentou fazer um join pelos ids?

Comment: eu não sabia fazer com mais de um join, faço de uma forma que agora que vi, é muito mais confusa. o pessoal ajudou muito a simplificar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Murilo,

Utilize a query abaixo para ter o resultado esperado.

```
SELECT
    C.NOME_CARTA,
    E.NOME_EDICAO,
    E.SERIAL,
    T.TIPO,
    C.EFEITO_DESC,
    C.ATK,
    C.DEF,
    C.LINK_IMG,
    A.ATRIBUTO,
    C.ID_LRL,
    C.QUANTIDADE
FROM
    CARTAS C 
    INNER JOIN ATRIBUTOS A ON A.ID = C.ID_ATRIBUTO
    INNER JOIN EDICOES E ON E.ID = C.ID_EDICAO
    INNER JOIN TIPOS T ON T.ID = C.ID_TIPO
```

Neste caso, foram realizados os joins para relacionar a tabela **Cartas** com as demais, vale ressaltar que foram atribuídos apelidos (*alias*) para as tabelas *(e.g. C, A, E, T)*.

Abraço,

Answer (score 2):

Faz a ligação usando `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.nome_carta, b.nome_edicao, b.serial, c.tipo, a.efeito_desc, a.atk, a.def, a.link_img, d.atributo, a.id_lrl, a.quantidade FROM cartas a
INNER JOIN edicoes b ON a.id_edicao = b.ID
INNER JOIN tipos c ON a.id_tipo = c.ID
INNER JOIN atributos d ON a.id_atributo = d.ID
```

No caso do `lrl` coloquei o `id` porque você não passou a estrutura dessa tabela.

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer o join entre as tabelas, relacionando-as pelas respectivas chaves estrangeiras:

```
Select
    c.nome_carta,
    e.nome_edicao,
    e.serial,
    t.tipo,
    c.efeito_desc,
    c.atk,
    c.def,
    c.link_img,
    a.atributo,
    c.id_lrl,
    c.quantidade
from cartas c 
inner join edicoes e on e.id = c.id_edicao
inner join tipos t on t.id = c.id_tipo
inner join atributo a on a.id = c.id_atributo
```